# Will unused placeholders in tensorflow affect the result?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, neural-network, placeholder

I had an unused placeholder in my code which was designed for further purposes. However, I found adding or not of it will affect the cost for each epoch and event the final result (e.g. accuracy, auc). I have checked that it wasn't connected to the computational graph since the placeholder was added on top of a complete program and it appears only once in the code. Since my project is a bit huge to reproduce, I tried to reproduce it using a simple code piece copied from a blog https://adventuresinmachinelearning.com/python-tensorflow-tutorial/.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
tf.random.set_random_seed(1234)

mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/", one_hot=True)
# Python optimisation variables
learning_rate = 0.5
epochs = 10
batch_size = 100

# declare the training data placeholders
# input x - for 28 x 28 pixels = 784
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])
# now declare the output data placeholder - 10 digits
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])

# zz = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name='zz') <--- the added placeholder

# now declare the weights connecting the input to the hidden layer
W1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([784, 300], stddev=0.03), name='W1')
b1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([300]), name='b1')
# and the weights connecting the hidden layer to the output layer
W2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([300, 10], stddev=0.03), name='W2')
b2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([10]), name='b2')

# calculate the output of the hidden layer
hidden_out = tf.add(tf.matmul(x, W1), b1)
hidden_out = tf.nn.relu(hidden_out)

# now calculate the hidden layer output - in this case, let's use a softmax activated
# output layer
y_ = tf.nn.softmax(tf.add(tf.matmul(hidden_out, W2), b2))

y_clipped = tf.clip_by_value(y_, 1e-10, 0.9999999)
cross_entropy = -tf.reduce_mean(tf.reduce_sum(y * tf.log(y_clipped)
                                              + (1 - y) * tf.log(1 - y_clipped), axis=1))

# add an optimiser
optimiser = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(cross_entropy)

# finally setup the initialisation operator
init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()

# define an accuracy assessment operation
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y, 1), tf.argmax(y_, 1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))

# start the session
with tf.Session() as sess:
    # initialise the variables
    sess.run(init_op)
    total_batch = int(len(mnist.train.labels) / batch_size)
    for epoch in range(epochs):
        avg_cost = 0
        for i in range(total_batch):
            batch_x, batch_y = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size=batch_size)
            _, c = sess.run([optimiser, cross_entropy],
                            feed_dict={x: batch_x, y: batch_y})
        avg_cost += c / total_batch
        print("Epoch:", (epoch + 1), "cost =", "{:.3f}".format(avg_cost))
    print(sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images, y: mnist.test.labels}))
```

I used `tf.random.set_random_seed(1234)` to ensure that the random initialization of each round is the same (not sure if it can be done but the results are consistent across multiple runs).
By adding the placeholder, the cost for epoch 1 would be 0.000, while by removing it, the cost would be 0.001.

Although in this simple example, the final accuracy stays the same (accuracy=0.9783), in my code, this operation affects a lot (adding the placeholder actually improves the AUC value for a binary classification problem). And if I changed the type of this placeholder, e.g. from placeholder to sparse_placeholder, the cost would also change (accuracy=0.9772 in this example). So I am wondering why the unused placeholder also has come contributions to the result, and how can I debug such a problem?

Thanks in advance! Anyone can directly copy paste and use python + name to run the code after the installation of TensorFlow 1.12+ and observe the differences by uncommenting the placeholder zz or not.

Plus: I see this post with similar issue and am reading thru https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/19171

Comment: I tried TF 1.12 and I get random results regardless of whether I comment that line or not. Did you get consistent results over multiple trials when you either comment or uncomment that line? To me it looks like there's some other randomness playing in the code.

Comment: @thushv89. Yes, I ran each for 5 times and got consistent results. Did you get a final accuracy as 0.9772 or 0.9783 or different? To be honest, I also doubt there might be some other random issues but I am not sure where.